# How to update a table with SUM function?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table like this and let's call it table1

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ A  ║  B           ║ Total║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║ 12 ║   -1         ║ 1016 ║
║ 12 ║   250        ║  234 ║
║  2 ║   -1         ║  342 ║
║ 20 ║   250        ║  959 ║
║  4 ║   -1         ║  232 ║
║  4 ║   250        ║  223 ║
║  5 ║   -1         ║  123 ║
║  6 ║   250        ║    9 ║
║  6 ║   251        ║    8 ║
║  7 ║    -1        ║    1 ║
║  7 ║   250        ║    12║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

I have another table and let's call it table2.

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ SL ║  A1          ║ Total║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║  I           ║      ║
║  2 ║  J           ║      ║
║  3 ║  K           ║      ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

Wherever the -1 with other number appeared in table1, that total has to be added with 'I' in table2, except -1 with 2.

So the -1 and 2 has to be added to the 'K' in the table2 and

wherever the 250 and 251 appears, that total has to be added to 'J' in table2

Answer (score 0):

The first sum can be computed as follows:

```
UPDATE table2
SET Total = (SELECT SUM(Total)
             FROM table1
             WHERE B = -1
               AND A != 2)
WHERE A1 = 'I';
```

The other two are left as an exercise …

Comment: thank you so much for answering. However, it only works for -1 and 2.
For other numbers in table1 and column A there are some dupllication are there.

Comment: So when I do the query as --(where B = -1

Comment: and A = 12,
and A = 4
and A = 5 
and A = 7 ) it is calculating but shows the wrong value.

Comment: Why are you checking for 12/4/5/7? That is not what you've described in the question.

Comment: Yeah, But I need this requirement too.